# Why do I get two different answers? Using Calculus and Using Newton for Distance/Velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

**Why do I get two different answers?**

> QUESTION: How long does it take to slow down from 8000 m/s to 6000 m/s with an acceleration of -400 m/s^2 ?

GIVENS
D distance
V velocity
T time
V initial velocity 8000 m/s
V** final velocity 6000 m/s
A acceleration -400 m/s^2

FORMULA 1
D = AT^2 + VT
D = -400T^2 + 8000T
V = D'
V = -800T + 8000 (first derivative)
Setting T=0, we find V=8000, which is correct for initial velocity.
Setting V=V**=6000 for final velocity, we find:
V = -800T + 8000 = 6000
T = 2.5

FORMULA 2
V** = V + AT
6000 = 8000 + -400T
-2000 = -400T
T = 5

I do not understand why these formulas are giving two different answers. **Thank you!**

Answer (score 1):

The formula 2 is correct and it gives correct answer t=5s. But formula 1 is wrong. The correct formula is $D=\frac {1}{2}at^2+vt$. If you differentiate  $D=at^2+vt$, you will get $v=v_0+2at$, where  $v_0$ is initial velocity. That is wrong.
So the correct answer is t=5s.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula 1 is incorrect as the correct formula is -
 s = ut + 1/2 at^2 
But your second formula is still correct. 
So Try again and you will be getting a correct answer.

Thanks, if see some efforts in my answer please upvote.